# Is is possible to sort by a combination of fileds and directions?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

Is is possible to sort by a combination of fileds and directions? I.E:

```
let $list := (<a id="1">A</a>, <a id="2">A</a>, <a id="3">B</a>)
let $ordered :=
    for $item in $list
        order by $item/text ascending, $item/@id descending
        return fn:data($item/@id)
return 
    if(fn:deep-equal((2,1,3),$ordered)) then "PASS" else "FAIL"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're sorting on `$item/text` (which means the element `<text/>` inside `$item`) instead on its contents which are addressed by the function `$item/text()`.

```
let $list := (<a id="1">A</a>, <a id="2">A</a>, <a id="3">B</a>)
for $item in $list
  order by $item/text() ascending, $item/@id descending
  return fn:data($item/@id)
```

Will yield desired output `(2,1,3)`.